# Removing blank lines in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

I'm using:

```
<xsl:template match="material_id | location_code"></xsl:template>
```

To get rid of elements in the source XML called `material_id` and `location_code`, but whitespace lines remain, leaving an output XML something like:

```
<entries>
    <Identity>conflab1</Identity>


    <price>24.36</price>
    <pricedate>15-Jul-2010 13:35:18 UTC</price_date>
</entries>
```

How should I stop it from leaving the newline characters?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>
```

at the top of the document.

Comment: This removes ALL white space, i.e. the document is afterwards one giganticly long singe line. How can one remove just the empty lines as was originally asked?

Comment: Adding `<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>` as well did the trick for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should combine strip-space and preserve-space together, so that you strip all spaces except those you define, eg:

```
<xsl:preserve-space  elements="Identity price price_date"/>
<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_strip-space.asp