# Spaces in output

Tags: xslt, whitespace, xslt-2.0, removing-whitespace

I am trying to transform an xml document into another document to get a comma dlimited string. However, when I transform I see a lot of spaces.

I am not sure what is causing this and what should I do to fix this issue -

## XML File Input

```
    <File>
<row>
    <wid>WID0001</wid>
    <xtn>Leave Record</xtn>
    <status>In Process</status>
    <eid>E001</eid>
    <amt>5000</amt>
</row>


<row>
    <wid>WID0003</wid>
    <xtn>Leave Record</xtn>
    <status>In Process</status>
    <eid>E005</eid>
    <amt>3000</amt>
</row>

<row>
    <wid>WID0010</wid>
    <xtn>Leave Record</xtn>
    <status>In Process</status>
    <eid>E010</eid>
    <amt>7000</amt>
</row>


<row>
    <wid>WID0007</wid>
    <xtn>Leave Record</xtn>
    <status>In Process</status>
    <eid>E010</eid>
    <amt>0000</amt>
</row>

<row>
    <wid>WID0050</wid>
    <xtn>Leave Record</xtn>
    <status>In Process</status>
    <eid>E025</eid>
    <amt>750000</amt>
</row>

</File>
```

And the XSLT -

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:this="http://abogusurl.com">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

        <xsl:template match="/File">
            <widlist>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </widlist>
        </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="row">
            <xsl:value-of select="wid" /> 
            <xsl:value-of select="','" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widlist x xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:this="http://abogusurl.com">
WID0001,


WID0003,

WID0010,


WID0007,

WID0050,

</widlist>
```

How do I eliminate the spaces?

Comment: There are some typos in the code snippet here: The `</xsl:choose>` end tag should be removed, it should have `<xsl:value-of select="wid" />`, right? (the last part is truncated in you snippet).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing blank lines in XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265244/removing-blank-lines-in-xslt)

Comment: I edited the code snippet to fixes the problems I described in my first comment here. I also tweaked the indenting of the code block, because your original formatting was causing it to get garbled. (Every line of all code blocks need to be indented by at least 4 spaces for the SO formatter to recognize them as such.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think adding `<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>` will do what you want.

Comment: @sideshwbarker Thanks. That did not seem to help.

Comment: OK, gimme a couple minutes to actually try something. (I posted that from answer in a hurry from my mobile.)

Comment: Revised my answer. The above should work for you as expected.

Comment: Thanks . That worked. Any explanation as to why the spaces got added?

Comment: IIRC from what I remember about XSLT (I used to do a lot of programming in it, but it’s been a while…) it’s just something like: the default behavior in XSLT or a template is to preserve in the output all the (inter-element) whitespace from the source. So if you change your stylesheet to just have `<xsl:template match="row"/>` (an empty template for matching `row` elements), it will just output all the whitespace. `<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>` simply overrides that default XSLT behavior, for all elements. (Which is sometimes not what you actually want, but at least in this case, it is).

Comment: @StillStumbling The real reason why you have all that whitespace in your output is that you're doing `<xsl:apply-templates />` when you should be doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>`. Your version applies the templates to the text nodes in-between the rows, too - and the default template rules copy these text nodes into your output.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML has `text()` nodes between the `row` elements. The [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) preserve them in the output.

You can suppress those `text()` nodes by adding an empty template that matches those whitespace-only text nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/File">
        <widlist>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </widlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:value-of select="wid"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--suppress whitespace-only text nodes-->
    <xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could also have the empty template match `File/text()`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/File">
        <widlist>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </widlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:value-of select="wid"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--suppress (whitespace) text nodes that are children of File-->
    <xsl:template match="File/text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or you can exclude those `File/text()` nodes by only applying templates to the `row` elements in the File template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/File">
        <widlist>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
        </widlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:value-of select="wid"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All of these solutions remove the extra whitespace and linebreaks and produce the following output:

```
<widlist>WID0001,WID0003,WID0010,WID0007,WID0050,</widlist>
```

This implementation is currently producing a trailing comma in the `widlist`.

You can fix that by changing the row template:

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:value-of select="wid"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

If you are using XSLT 2.0 and want to produce a comma separated list, you could shorten your stylesheet to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/File">
        <widlist>
            <xsl:value-of select="row/wid" separator=","/>
        </widlist>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```